# Is it possible to output logs in JSON format for graphql-yoga?

Tags: javascript, node.js, kubectl, graphql-js

I use [graphql-yoga](https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga) and I'd like the format of my logs to be JSON. How can I do it?

The current state is the following:

```
$ kubectl logs ...
(node:21) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change log format using `kubectl` but you could change logging driver in your container runtime, for example [docker](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/json-file/).